# Некорректная работа scanf

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. Моя программа на C работает не так, как я планировал.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
char InputAgain;
int main()
{
    double a = 0;
    printf("Input argument a: \n");

    if (scanf("%lf", &a) == 0)
    {
        printf("Wrong input argument X. Press y - to continue, other - to return back: \n ");
        scanf("%c", &InputAgain);

        if (InputAgain == 'y')
            scanf("%lf", &a);
        else
        {
            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что оператор `scanf("%c", &InputAgain)` (при выполнении условия в `if`) НЕ выполняется. Вообще.

Во время отладки я увидел, что переменной `InputAgain` присваивается значение переменной `a`, после выполнения этого оператора: `scanf("%lf", &a)`.

Не знаете, как исправить это?

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: 1. [mcve]. 2. http://ideone.com/

Comment: Тут что-то не так со скобками. Скорее всего, вы должны поставить закрывающуюся фигурную скобку перед else. И функция main также не закрывается. В случае, когда после условного оператора вообще нет фигурных скобок, выполняется только следующая за ним функция.

Answer (score 2):

У вас просто НЕ считалось значение `a` (раз `==0`), а раз НЕ считалось, то осталось в буфере.

Считайте всю введенную строку , сбросьте буфер. Иначе в вашу переменную попадает первый символ того, что было введено ранее...

```
if (scanf("%lf", &a) == 0) {
    while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Comment: Неплохо бы по EOF тоже цикл покидать...